# What are the biblical arguments that if you sin you lose your salvation as soon as you sin?

Tags: grace, assurance-of-salvation

I consider the grace of the Holy Spirit as an enablement to be blameless in holiness when we detach from the body and be saved (not to sin and still being blameless). I believe that when someone sins he loses salvation. I don't want to argue about *sola fide* and things like that, I'm Protestant, but Pentecostal and I follow the doctrine of the Holy Spirit (total separation from distractions that keep us away from God even though it's not written in the bible). I'd like to know some arguments to defend my idea; those below are the ones I know so far:

- Then, after desire has conceived, it gives birth to sin; and sin, when it is full-grown, gives birth to death. (James 1:15)
- Paul apostle advised us to become blameless on holiness as a requirement to be saved:
  "Now may the God of peace Himself sanctify you completely; and may your whole spirit, soul, and body be preserved blameless at the coming of our Lord Jesus Christ." (Thessalonians 5:23)
- "Do everything without grumbling or arguing,  so that you may become blameless and pure, “children of God without fault in a warped and crooked generation.” Then you will shine among them like stars in the sky." (Philippians 2:14-15). This leads us to understand that this church was in the sin of dissension and would have to repent to become blameless.
- Salvation by grace in Ephesians 2:8 implies that we receive the Holy Spirit by grace and enable us to do good works to be holy when the Lord asks our soul. This seems clean by the verse below:
  "He saved us, not because of righteous things we had done, but because of his mercy. He saved us through the washing of rebirth and renewal by the Holy Spirit." (Titus 3:5). The first salvation through baptism and a power of the Holy Spirit, however often we may lose our salvation sometimes, to enable us to live a life which is in short blameless in holiness to give us a saving confidence in the final judgment where everyone is judged (not just rewarded) for their works at Revelation 20:12.

I know this sounds like a doctrine of salvation only by works, but it is the grace of the Holy Spirit that enables us for these works. I would like to know if there are more biblical arguments for this and if this branch has a name (in my country there is this name I mentioned, but I believe it is not formalized in theology).

Comment: Do you mean to say that you are constantly losing and re-applying for salvation?  How terrifying!

Comment: You seem to adhere to a position that virtually no other Christians hold to, and are asking for biblical arguments to justify your position. If other Christians believed this also then we could answer how they justified the view, but I don't think there are. If you know of another group that believes this we might be able to tell you their justifications, but without that I think this is just asking for opinions.

Comment: @DJClayworth, it's not just your opinion; I will happily go on record concurring with you . This is somewhat related to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91540, and Davi and I discussed it at some length in chat (see link in comments on question). Honestly, I think this is a somewhat Roman Catholic position, though IIUC not even Catholicism holds such a position with respect to *venial* sin. I would definitely say that, in my understanding, this is *not* a mainstream Protestant perspective.

Comment: @MikeBorden the peace of the Lord Jesus, terrifying is to gain eternity, not 10, 100, or 1 trillion years, but eternity regardless of what you do on earth (not even 80 years).

Comment: Will you, then, stand before God some day and demand from Him what your behavior on earth has earned?  At the beginning of your question you say you believe this way "even though it's not written in the bible".  You should study the first epistle of John which has much to say about the link between how we live as Christians and experiencing assurance of the salvation we have already been given.  It is possible to lose the "experience of assurance" through sin and regain "assurance" through genuine repentance and confession all the while never actually losing salvation itself.

Answer (score 2):

#### Methodological considerations

I think I understand what you're trying to do: you are creating *your own* theology based on *your own* interpretation of the Bible, and you're wondering whether there is an *existing branch* that matches your interpretation.  You also want to bolster your theology with further Biblical arguments.  You are thinking that Pentecostal theology is the closest to your theology.  But I agree with [@Matthew's comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91575/what-are-the-biblical-arguments-that-if-you-sin-you-lose-your-salvation-as-soon#comment257651_91575) that this view is not mainstream Protestant, and as I argue below, it's actually close to Catholicism!

From your writeup, I can see how your notions of grace, salvation & sanctification, body vs. spirit, and how the Holy Spirit works within us **are rather different than established Protestant theologies** such as Reformed, Lutheran, Methodist, and even Pentecostal!  Hence I agree with [@DJClayworth's comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91575/what-are-the-biblical-arguments-that-if-you-sin-you-lose-your-salvation-as-soon#comment257646_91575).

While everyone has a "right" to create their own theologies based on extreme form of private interpretation of the Bible, most Christians don't read the Bible in a vacuum.  They would

- try to exegete carefully how the Biblical authors *themselves* define theological terms like grace, sin, justification, holiness
- dialogue with communally respected theologians like Martin Luther, John Calvin, and John Wesley to "tweak" the theology of how God works out our salvation through the ministry of the Holy Spirit
- create a theological model of the human person that fits all the empirical facts as well as how grace & sin operates within that model
- read at least one systematic theology book that bring a certain cohesion to Bible interpretation as well as showing connection with common topics in theology, showing you a link between Trinity, the Fall, Salvation, and Eschatology, for example.

#### Comments on your view from the perspective of common Christian theologies

1. Most Protestants (especially Wesleyan and Pentecostals) as well as Catholics believe that sanctification (growth in holiness) is *gradual* and that there is some level of cooperation of our will with the Holy Spirit who infuses grace to our being to make us conform closer to the image of Christ.  So the "enablement" you speak of **is not a switch**, despite Pentecostal practice of Spirit baptism (equivalent to Catholic sacrament of confirmation).  Progress and backsliding is very much a reality, **and should *not* be construed as a loss of salvation**, because unless the sin is "mortal" (understood in Catholicism) or unless we "grieve the spirit" (understood in Protestantism), the life of the Spirit remains within us despite the influence of our remaining sinful nature.
2. *Sola Fide* refers to justification: reconciliation with God, and an imputation of blamelessness / righteousness before God.  Works is our response, and is *not* part of justification.  Instead, sanctification (understood by Wesleyan & Pentecostal) should be heavily linked with union with Christ, who through his Holy Spirit imparts his grace that in turn **empowers** us ("empower", not "enable", to highlight the synergism) to choose and do good.
3. In Catholicism, when we sin "venially" we don't lose salvation.  But "mortal" sin is the working of our soul that has so reject God that we are most likely lost before we sin !  For example, a person planning a premeditated murder has probably already lost his salvation before he carries out his act.

#### Answering your question

You asked:

> What are the biblical arguments that if you sin you lose your salvation as soon as you sin?

If the sin is "mortal", the Catholic Biblical argument can be read in a *Catholic Answer* article by Catholic apologist Tim Staples [Mortal and Venial Sin?](https://www.catholic.com/magazine/online-edition/mortal-and-venial-sin) citing Catholic interpretation of:

- **James 2:10-11**: the context of James 2 doesn't allow one to say that all sins are equal, but simply that one cannot pick and choose which laws to obey
- **Matt 5:19**: Jesus makes a distinction between "one of the least" of these commandments where the offender still remain "in the kingdom of heaven".  This becomes the basis of venial sin, which contrasts with a mortal sin that Jesus described in Matt 5:22 with the consequence in vv. 28-29.
- **Matt 12:32**: This is the famously controversial verse about speaking against the Holy Spirit that cannot be forgiven, again contrasting less vs. more serious sins.  In contrast 1 John 5:16-18 teaches that venial sins are not "deadly":

  > If anyone sees his brother committing a sin that is not a deadly sin, he will ask, and **God will give him life for those whose sin is not deadly**. There is sin which is deadly; I do not say one is to pray for that. All wrongdoing is sin, **but there is sin which is not deadly**. We know that anyone born of God does not sin, but He who is born of God keeps him, and the evil one does not touch him.

> I know this sounds like a doctrine of salvation only by works, but it is the grace of the Holy Spirit that enables us for these works. I would like to know if there are more biblical arguments for this and if this branch has a name

While Catholicism is **not** salvation ONLY by works, Catholics are super serious that the Holy Spirit works in manifold ways (including through sacraments) to empower us to become more holy.  This point, and the above point about losing salvation, is the reason why I suggest that **the name of the branch you're looking for is *Catholicism***, as @Matthew also suggested.

But if Catholicism is not for you, I recommend you choose a systematic theology book written from a Protestant theology you trust.  For Pentecostalism, one example is Stanley Horton's 1994 book [Systematic Theology: A Pentecostal Perspective](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/255467.Systematic_Theology).

Comment: I got this particular interpretation with the Holy Spirit I don't trust renowned theologians just because the system "defined" them as renowned for example it is more than obvious that the blasphemy against the Holy Spirit is to attribute works of satan to the action of the Spirit, but many make this more complex and use human subjectivism to distort the truth summing it up to deny grace regardless it seems there is no name for the stated idea.